# §5.3.5/10 doesn't seem to apply to class-specific versions of the deallocation function. Is that correct?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, c++14, delete-operator

**§5.3.5[expr.delete]/10:**

> If the type is complete and if deallocation function lookup finds both
>   a usual deallocation function with only a pointer parameter and a
>   usual deallocation function with both a pointer parameter and a size
>   parameter, then the selected deallocation function shall be the one
>   with two parameters. Otherwise, the selected deallocation function
>   shall be the function with one parameter.

In the snippet below we try to verify the alluded paragraph for deallocation functions in the global scope and in class scope. `g++` and `VS2015` choose the correct deallocation function in the global scope, but they fail to invoke the two parameter deallocation function in class scope. Why is this?

`clang` seems to fail on both scopes. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/073c43a6c9b7ecd9).

```
#include <iostream>

void operator delete(void* p) noexcept
{
    free(p);
    std::cout << "operator delete(void*)" << '\n';
}

void operator delete(void* p, size_t s)
{
    free(p);
    std::cout << "operator delete(void* , size_t)  size_t = " << s << '\n';
}

class A { int i = 1; };

class Base {
public:
    void operator delete(void* p) {
        free(p);
        std::cout << "Base::operator delete(void*)" << '\n';
    }
    void operator delete(void* p, size_t s) {
        free(p);
        std::cout << "Base::operator delete(void*, size_t)  size_t = " << s << '\n';
    }
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int i;
public:
    ~Derived() {};
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A{};
    delete a;

    Base* b = new Derived{};
    delete b;
}
```

This is the output obtained by `g++` and `VS2015`:

```
operator delete(void* , size_t)  size_t = 4
Base::operator delete(void*)
```

Output from `clang`:

```
operator delete(void*)
Base::operator delete(void*)
```

Comment: Hint for the class scope question: look up the definition of "usual deallocation function". As to clang with global scope deallocation function, it requires `-fsized-deallocation`.

Comment: @T.C. §3.7.4.2/2 doesn't specify which one is the usual deallocation function when both functions are declared in class scope. How should I interpret this?

Comment: @T.C. I'm sorry. §3.7.4.2/2 does specify that the deallocation function with  one parameter is the usual deallocation function when both functions are declared in class scope. You gave me the answer already. Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky The paragraph contains this sentence: `If a class T has a member deallocation function named operator delete with exactly one parameter, then that function is a usual deallocation function.` without regard whether the other function with two parameters is declared or not.

Comment: @T.C. Is it correct to say that clang is compliant to the Standard, when it requires -fsized-deallocation, to come up with the expected result?

Comment: And it also requires `-std=c++14 -pedantic`. So what?

Comment: @T.C. `clang` doesn't require `-std=c++14` neither `-pedantic` for this specific result. But it requires `-fsized-deallocation`.

Comment: That is not the point. The point is that compilers are free to define their "full conformance mode" flags however they want.

Comment: @Belloc, `then that function is a usual deallocation function` from §3.7.4.2/2 would specify **a** possibility, couldn't there be other ones? I didn't understand why it didn't chose the sized deallocation from class scope.

Comment: @PauloTorrens No because in sequence, the next sentence says (emphasis mine): `If class T **does not** declare such an operator delete but does declare a member deallocation function named operator delete with exactly two parameters, the second of which has
type std::size_t, then this function is a usual deallocation function`. That is, the deallocation function with two parameters is a usual deallocation function only if the function with one parameter is **not** declared in class scope.